# @azure/functions node module removed after Azure Function VSCode deployment

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Every time I deploy my Azure Function app via VSCode the @azure/functions node module keeps getting removed and the import statement shows an error that this module can't be found. I understand this package isn't needed in Azure but how can I configure my launch.json to re-install this automatically after deployment is complete? Now I have to manually run `npm install @azure/functions --force` and restart VSCode to have the import recognized again.

Here is my package.json dependencies section:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/service-bus": "^7.3.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "jest": "^27.2.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Here is my launch.json:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `.vscode/settings.json` file contains `azureFunctions.preDeployTask` it automatically prone your node modules while deploying.

This is controlled by the setting `azureFunctions.preDeployTask` in `.vscode/settings.json`, with the tasks defined in `.vscode/tasks.json`. We write these files when creating a project as a starting point, but I would definitely recommend customizing these to your tastes. Check similar issue discussion here [link 1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1528), [link 2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1930)

In `.vscode/settings.json file contains azureFunctions.postDeployTask` is used to install the node modules after the post deployment. You can try this as well other wise try to remove both preDeployTask and postDeployTask. Refer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1528#issuecomment-592277976)

[image]

Refer more info here [vscode-azurefunctions Project Structure](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/wiki/Project-Structure)